# Ads on Checkout a Bad Idea™?

Tags: xss, credit-card, defense

Is it a categorically bad practice to run third-party aggregated ads on a checkout page where sensitive information is entered?

This sends of all kinds of alarm bells for me, but I've had a difficult time convincing the upper ranks that something should be done. Can anyone provided some reputable sources that explain this well, or perhaps tell me to chill out?

Comment: I see the answer below explains why you should not expose your clients to the dangers.  I would only add that you would be very wise to first collect payment before showing any adds that might make them click away from checkout.

Comment: Ads are a bad no matter where they are used.

Answer (score 5):

If third party ads are embedded as iframes they might be used for social and UI redressing attacks, i.e. simulate warnings, buttons, input fields for credit card or similar to trick the user. But with iframes it cannot be used to  steal user data from the original page. If ads are instead embedded as Javascript it gets even worse, since this way the code in the ads has full access to your site and can read and manipulate the page, which includes reading any data entered by the user.

This problem is not only restricted to the checkout page and also not only to ads but is relevant whenever you include third party Javascript libraries into your site and thus affects also social media buttons or similar. If you include third party script into a page  the third party can get full control of this page it cause actions with the identity of the currently logged in user.